# Cannot find module after project compilation

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here is my package.json:

```
   {
      "main": "./build/app.js",
      "types": "./build/app.d.ts",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && node build/app.js",
        "dev": "concurrently \"tsc -w \" \"nodemon ./build/app.js\"",
        "lint": "tslint ./src"
      },
    }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es6",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "outDir": "build",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "declaration": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "files": [
     "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
     "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

`Error: Cannot find module 'controllers/index'`. I try to import this file like this: `import controllers from 'controllers/index'` in app.ts.

[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3FYO.png)

So, how can I add relative path to my compile folder "build"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use module alias.

There are many approaches to it, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias. Or if your are using Webpack, they also have this feature, just google "webpack alias".

Comment: That is the point. I want to import files like 'controllers/index'. In the future, I don't want to import files this way '../../../'. 
"baseUrl": "src" sets my basic folder, but in the 'build' it doesn't work. After compilation, I want 'build' folder to be my relative path for .js files.

Comment: So, now in src I can easy import with initial folder itself.

Comment: I suggest against this practice. Keep your file structure as flat as possible. I used to do things just like you do, but this approach is a source of problems and counter-productivity.

Comment: I can't agree. Every time to write '../../' is so annoying. Maybe it's not so significant in node.js project, but, for example, in react project it is essential. Anyway, maybe you do know the answer?